# Flake8 failed to load plugin "N8" on custom Formatter

Tags: python, python-3.x, flake8

I want to build a custom formatter for class and function names.

According to this [doc](https://flake8.readthedocs.io/en/2.0/warnings.html) it says that the naming convention falls under the `N8**` warning code.

After following [this](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/plugin-development/formatters.html) tutorial with the help of a [sublink](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/plugin-development/registering-plugins.html#register-a-plugin) this is the resultant code

**setup.py**

```
from __future__ import with_statement
import setuptools

requires = [
    "flake8 > 3.0.0",
]

setuptools.setup(
    name="flake8_example",
    license="MIT",
    version="0.1.0",
    description="our extension to flake8",
    author="Me",
    author_email="example@example.com",
    url="https://gitlab.com/me/flake8_example",
    packages=[
        "flake8_example",
    ],
    install_requires=requires,
    entry_points={
        'flake8.extension': [
            'N8 = flake8_example:Example',
        ],
    },
    classifiers=[
        "Framework :: Flake8",
        "Environment :: Console",
        "Intended Audience :: Developers",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Programming Language :: Python",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 2",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules",
        "Topic :: Software Development :: Quality Assurance",
    ],
)
```

**flake8_example.py**

```
from flake8.formatting import base

class Example(base.BaseFormatter):
    """Flake8's example formatter."""

    def format(self, error):
        return 'Example formatter: {0!r}'.format(error)
```

I setup it up by running `pip install --editable .`

Then to test it out I ran `flake8 --format=example main.py`

It throws this error:

> flake8.exceptions.FailedToLoadPlugin: Flake8 failed to load plugin "N8" due to 'module' object has no attribute 'Example'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you're trying to write a *formatter* you need to read the documentation a bit more closely. In the [registering](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/plugin-development/registering-plugins.html) section of the documentation it says:

> Flake8 presently looks at three groups:
>
> - `flake8.extension`
> - `flake8.listen`
> - `flake8.report`
>
> If your plugin is one that adds checks to Flake8, you will use
>   flake8.extension. If your plugin automatically fixes errors in code,
>   you will use flake8.listen. **Finally, if your plugin performs extra
>   report handling (formatting, filtering, etc.) it will use
>   flake8.report.**

(Emphasis mine.)

That means your `setup.py` should look like this:

```
entry_points = {
    'flake8.report': [
        'example = flake8_example:Example',
    ],
}
```

If your `setup.py` properly installs your package then running

```
flake8 --format=example ...
```

Should work just fine. The exception you're seeing, however, is due to the module either not having a class named Example. You should investigate whether `packages` will pick up a single file module or if you need to restructure your plugin so that it looks like:

```
flake8_example/
    __init__.py
    ...
```

As that may be why your setup.py is not working appropriately.